# How to filter products collection using active filters?

Tags: php, magento

Could you please help me with a solution as to how I can apply active filters to products collection?

For example:

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
$productsCollection = $_category->getProductCollection();
```

Fetching active filters:

```
$_filters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();
```

How can I filter products in $productsCollection using $_filters ?

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

Magento applies filters to a collection in function [Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Attribute::applyFilterToCollection](https://github.com/varinen/Magento-Community-1.6.2.0-0.1/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php#L53). Following its logic you could use this code:

```
$_filters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();
$productsCollection = $_category->getProductCollection();
foreach ($_filters as $filterItem) {
    $filter = $filterItem->getFilter(); /**Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute**/
    $attribute  = $filter->getAttributeModel();
    $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
    $tableAlias = $attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_idx';
    $conditions = array(
        "{$tableAlias}.entity_id = e.entity_id",
        $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.attribute_id = ?",
        $attribute->getAttributeId()),
        $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.store_id = ?", $collection->getStoreId()),
            $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.value = ?", $value)
        );

    $productsCollection->getSelect()->join(
        array($tableAlias => $filter->getResource()->getMainTable()),
        implode(' AND ', $conditions),
        array()
        );

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You made me closer in solving my issue :)
I have few more questions:

1. As far as I understand $value is a value of filter. How can I get it?

2. If I call $filter->getResource()->getMainTable() then it leads to following error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function getMainTable() on a non-object in Z:\home\mysite\www\app\design\frontend\default\mysite\template\catalog\product\list.phtml on line 83.

If I print out
var_dump($filter->getResource());

then I see
NULL

Could you please help here?

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `$filter->getResource()->getMainTable()` you can use `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/layer_filter_attribute')->getMainTable();`. This should return table name "catalog_product_index_eav"

Comment: In case of a layered navigation filtering the filter value is fetched from the request object. Does your request have a parameter with the filter value? If yes, you could access it with `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam($attribute->getAttributeCode())`

Comment: Thank you, could you please review my new question?

Answer (score 1):

The error you get when selecting a category is that the filter object is of type `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Category` and has no property `attribute_model`. You must add a check to the filter loop to prevent this:

```
foreach($_filters as $filterItem)
{
    $filter = $filterItem->getFilter();
    if (!($filter instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute)) {
        continue;
    }
```

The problem with multiple select filter values can also be solved two ways. If you want the filter values applied in a OR fashion, do this:

```
   $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.value = in(?)", explode('_', Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam($attribute->getAttributeCode())))
```

If the filter values must be applied in an AND fashion, the procedure is a bit more complex. Basically you must perform multiple joins to the same table and have to provide a unique table alias for each join:

```
   $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
   $tableAlias = $attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_idx';

   $values = explode('_', Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam($attribute->getAttributeCode()));

   foreach ($values as $value) {
        $tableAliasModified = $tableAlias.'_'.$value;
        $conditions = array(
            "{$tableAliasModified}.entity_id = e.entity_id",
            $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAliasModified}.attribute_id = ?",
            $attribute->getAttributeId()),
            $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAliasModified}.store_id = ?", Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId()),
                $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAliasModified}.value = ?", $value)
            );

        $productsCollection->getSelect()->join(
            array($tableAliasModified => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/layer_filter_attribute')->getMainTable()),
            implode(' AND ', $conditions),
            array()
            );
    }
```

Comment: It is almost done, could you please help me with my final question?